# Custom ComboBoxModel. How to fire event correctly?

Tags: java, swing, events, combobox, listener

I have implemented my own ComboBoxModel:

```
public class MyComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel<MyType> 
                             implements ComboBoxModel<MyType> {}
```

Now I obviously need to override `public void setSelectedItem(Object item)`, but the documentation says the following:

> The implementation of this method should notify all registered `ListDataListeners` that the contents have changed.

To do so, I guess I need to use the method `AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Object, int, int)`. The Problem with `JComboBox` is, that one can set the selected item without it having to be in the list, so when `setSelectedItem(Object)` is called, I cannot necessarily determine the index of the item in question, since it need not be in the underlying model.

I found an answer to another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077192) which uses `fireContentsChanged(item, -1, -1)` in this case, but the person did not provide any details to that part of code. Now I am wondering, whether this was the correct way to deal with a changed selected item?

Should I ALWAYS use -1 as both indexes? Should I try and get the real index of an item, if it is actually in the model? Or should I do something entirely different?

Comment: That's how it is done in the `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

Comment: as you noticed, the doc is vague - so the only direction is to look into the default implementation. Using the -1 as the changed index has a certain logic, as the selectedItem is "outside" the usual index schema, independent of whether or not it actually is contained in the model. As listeners typically need to update something, the something-of-interest is the "special selected" not its location in the list. Just musing, though, can't look into the heads of the original developers :-)